# grep to multiple files in order to scan an input file once

Tags: bash, csv, grep

I have a hundred CSV files with 200k lines each, compressed to gzip.
All files with the same structure. The 15th and the 18th columns contain a companyID and  action.
Both columns are unique in a line.
I want to create one file per copanyID.action.
Now I run this command:

`zcat * | grep 'companyID.*action' | gzip > companyID.action.gz`

I pipe everything in order to avoid disk IO.

The problem is we have hundreds of companies and about 20 actions.
Running this command on every companyID X action scans the whole data each time.

I am looking for a solution that scan the input files once and write a line to the right file, if the file not exists create one.

I prefer bash or Golang code, but speed matter so every solution worth checking

Comment: What about `zcat`ing all the files and piping the output to `sort` by the relevant columns?

Comment: @choroba `sort` doesn't split the output into different files.

Comment: @Barmar: That would be the next step, but rather trivial once the data are sorted.

Comment: @choroba Isn't it the same problem? Why does putting all the rows for the same file together make it any easier?

Comment: @Barmar: It could still work if the whole structure is too large to keep in memory.

Comment: @choroba You seem to be assuming a particular solution that requires grouping all the rows before writing anything to the files.

Comment: @Barmar: Yes, that was the point of my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Do it with `awk`.

```
scat * | awk '{ print | "gzip > " $15 "." $18 ".gzip" }'
```

Comment: `shopt -s nullglob` will be useful before `scat *`.

Comment: If you have many patterns, Awk will run out of file handles. You could `close` after each write, but that will incur a significant performance penalty. Maybe switch to a more capable language in that case; this should be easy and comfortable in Python or Perl (or, I'm guessing, Ruby).

Comment: @tripleee If you close after each write, `gzip` will create a new file each time you write.

Comment: Yes, you have to change to an append redirect `>>` of course.

Comment: @tripleee That was how I originally wrote my answer, but I changed to use the pipe

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
zcat * |
awk -F, '{cmd="gzip >> \""$15"."$18".zip\""} cmd!=prev{close(prev)} {print | cmd; prev=cmd}'
```

With GNU awk you don't need the `cmd!=prev{close(prev)}` part and if you do:

```
zcat * |
sort -t, -k15,15 -k18,18 |
awk -F, '{cmd="gzip > \""$15"."$18".zip\""} cmd!=prev{close(prev)} {print | cmd; prev=cmd}'
```

it'll probably run faster since it'll only be opening/closing each output pipe once in the awk command, just depends how long the `sort` takes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `scat` does. I used `zcat` instead. I sorted all the lines of all the files by the relevant columns, then process the output in Perl, changing the output file when the values in the relevant columns change:

```
zcat *.csv.gz \
| sort -t, -k15,15 -k18,18 \
| perl -laF, -ne '
    if ($company ne $F[14] || $action ne $F[17]) {
        ($company, $action) = @F[14, 17];
        open FH, ">", "$company.$action.csv"
    }
    print FH $_'
gzip *.*.csv
```